# How to move part of file to its end

Tags: sed, text-processing

rpm automatically place a new installed kernel as the first option. However, I want to move it as the last one - to end of the file.

Grub configuration file looks like this:

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Fedora (2.6.29.6-217.2.7.fc11.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.29.6-217.2.7.fc11.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/main-root rhgb quiet
    initrd /initrd-2.6.29.6-217.2.7.fc11.x86_64.img
title Fedora (2.6.29.6-217.2.3.fc11.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.29.6-217.2.3.fc11.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/main-root rhgb quiet
    initrd /initrd-2.6.29.6-217.2.3.fc11.x86_64.img
title Fedora (2.6.29.6-213.fc11.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.29.6-213.fc11.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/main-root rhgb quiet
    initrd /initrd-2.6.29.6-213.fc11.x86_64.img
```

My goal is to move first option (217.2.3) to end. Now I figure out how to delete it:

```
sed -e '/(2.6.29.6-217.2.7.fc11.x86_64)/,+3d' /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

p command only prints current line (not as in vim, where it means paste).

Do you have any ideas how to automatically move this part of file to its end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to answer myself. :-)

```
sed '/\(2.6.18-157.el5\)/,+4 { H; d; }; $ { p; x; }' /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

If you are not fluent with sed (me neither), there is more verbose version

```
sed '
 /\(2.6.18-157.el5\)/,+3 { #Find line which contains version of our kernel in parentheses and took also 3 following lines
  H # Append this line into buffer
  d # Delete line
 }

 $ { # On the last line
 p # Print current line
 x # Change current line with buffer and vice versa
 # Afterwards sed print current line => in our case deleted line
 }' /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Answer (score 0):

A very similar task was covered extensively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix)

Yes, there is some satisfaction in a well crafted sed command, but I think I would tend to use an editor, so I could see the lines I was going to move around, and not have to worry about getting the line numbers wrong in a command.