# How to "grep" out specific line ranges of a file

Tags: command-line, grep

There are often times I will `grep -n` whatever file to find what I am looking for. Say the output is:

```
1234: whatev 1
5555: whatev 2
6643: whatev 3
```

If I want to then just extract the lines between 1234 and 5555, is there a tool to do that?  For static files I have a script that does `wc -l` of the file and then does the math to split it out with tail & head but that doesn't work out so well with log files that are constantly being written to.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Try using sed as mentioned on
http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-sed-to-extract-lines-in-text-file.html. For example use

```
sed '2,4!d' somefile.txt
```

to print from the second line to the fourth line of `somefile.txt`. (And don't forget to check http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html, sed is a wonderful tool.)

Comment: One useful follow up bit of information is how to prepend the line numbers onto the sed result... pipe it into nl  like so: `sed ''"$start"','"$end"'!d' somefile.txt | nl -ba -v$start`

Comment: @Scorchio What does `!d` mean?

Comment: @ManuelJordan `d` is the delete command of sed. `!` reverses the restriction (ie. in this case, the specified range). So `2,4!d` means dropping everything except lines 2-4.

Comment: @Scorchio thanks for the explanation. - Normally `!` go in the beginning - something like `!2,4d`

Comment: Does it delete the other lines from the file or just from the standard output?

Comment: @princess_hacker Sed doesn't touch the original file in itself. It just outputs the filtered and transformed parts of the file.

Answer (score 51):

The following command will do what you asked for "extract the lines between 1234 and 5555" in `someFile`.

```sh
sed -n '1234,5555p' someFile
```

Comment: I had to add `/` delimiters to make it work: `sed -n '/1234/,/5555/p' someFile`

Comment: small thing, but you don't need the quotes

Answer (score 14):

If I understand correctly, you want to find a pattern between two line numbers.  The awk one-liner could be

```
awk '/whatev/ && NR >= 1234 && NR <= 5555' file
```

You don't need to run `grep` followed by `sed`.

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'if (/whatev/ && $. >= 1234 && $. <= 5555) {print}' file
```

Answer (score 9):

Line numbers are OK if you can guarantee the position of what you want. Over the years, my favorite flavor of this has been something like this:

```
sed "/First Line of Text/,/Last Line of Text/d" filename
```

which deletes all lines from the first matched line to the last match, including those lines.

Use sed **-n** with "**p**" instead of "**d**" to print those lines instead.  Way more useful for me, as I usually don't know where those lines are.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this.  I used something like this to delete only the first line of a file if it matches a specific pattern: `sed '/^---$/,1d' filename`.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a file and make it executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
start=`grep -n $1 < $3 | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "couldn't find start pattern!" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
stop=`tail -n +$start < $3 | grep -n $2 | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1; exit ${PIPESTATUS[1]}`
if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "couldn't find end pattern!" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

stop=$(( $stop + $start - 1))

sed "$start,$stop!d" < $3
```

Execute the file with arguments (NOTE that the script does not handle spaces in arguments!):

1. Starting grep pattern
2. Stopping grep pattern
3. File path

To use with your example, use arguments: `1234 5555 myfile.txt`

Includes lines with starting and stopping pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lines instead of line ranges, you can do it with perl: eg. if you want to get line 1, 3 and 5 from a file, say /etc/passwd:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){if(++$l~~[1,3,5]){print}}' < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: FYI, That `$l` is "dollar el" not "dollar one".   A more perlish (i.e. shorter) command is `perl -ne 'if($.~~[1,3,5]){print}' /etc/passwd`.