# Extracting lines 1, 11, 21, etc. from a text file

Tags: shell

Is it possible to retrieve data from lines number 1, 11, 21 ,31 from a text file using Linux commands?

I need to do the same for 2, 12, 22, 32 and so on.

Comment: A little search would have given you a solution :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix

Comment: The 'a little search' solution is for discreet ranges of lines, which is a different problem from the one posed here.  None of the solutions in [SO 83329](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix) comes close to tackling this problem.

Comment: @Leffler Are you joking ? Should the answer also be rewriten for lines 1, 11, 21 and 31 because thinking 4 seconds or typing man is painful ?

Comment: @dystroy: I agree with Jonathan. What in the answers to that question shows how to select every nth line in a file? (I'm _not_ saying this hasn't been asked before - probably has, but the question you link to doesn't answer this question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '(NR % 10 == 1){ print }' your_input_file
```

For example:

```
 $ seq 1 100|awk '(NR%10 == 2){print}'
2
12
22
32
42
52
62
72
82
92
```

As [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) points out, you can parametrize the `awk` script to make it more easy to use. And given that `print` is the default action, you can simply write:

```
 $ seq 1 20|awk -v step=10 -v idx=3 'NR%step==idx'
3
13
```

Comment: +1. To parameterize: `awk -v skip=10 -v wanted=1 'NR%skip==wanted'`

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed much more useful generally. Hoisted it into the post.