# Extract section of a text file

Tags: text, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that will extract lines 6000 to 6999 in a give text file.  From googling I have come accross the following code - however this is giving me a blank output file.

```
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
type nul > nodedata.txt
set StartText=6000
set EndText=7000
set Flag=0
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type out.txt') do (
if /i "%StartText%" EQU "%%a" (set Flag=1) 
if /i "%EndText%" EQU "%%a" (set Flag=0) 
if !Flag! EQU 1 echo %%a >> nodedata1.txt
)
```

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and then see answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix) question... Windows is just not made for text processing...

A Windows user...

Comment: If Microsoft made a utility for this, it would spew messages like `Found 6000 in foo.txt. Copying Line 6000. Copying line 6001. ... Copying line 6999.  1000 line(s) copied.`   These would be mingled with the output, and require an option to disable them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and simple pure batch solution

```
for /l %%a in (6000,1,6999) do (
more C:\file.txt +%%a >>C:\extracted.txt
)
```

Comment: Your solution execute `more` command 1000 times, and each time open the output file and seeks for EOF to append the next line. This is not efficient...

Answer (score 1):

This is a Batch solution that run faster...

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
(for /F "skip=5999 delims=" %%a in (out.txt) do (
   echo %%a
   set /A count+=1
   if !count! equ 1000 goto endLoop
   )
) > nodedata1.txt
:endLoop
```