# How to use sed to remove the last n lines of a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to remove some *n* lines from the end of a file. Can this be done using sed?

For example, to remove lines from 2 to 4, I can use

```
$ sed '2,4d' file
```

But I don't know the line numbers.  I can delete the last line using

```
$sed $d file
```

but I want to know the way to remove *n* lines from the end. Please let me know how to do that using sed or some other method.

Comment: @arashkordi: that uses a line-count from the top of the file, not the bottom.

Comment: Related question on [superusers](http://superuser.com/q/471087/133552).

Comment: // , Perhaps consider rephrasing the question to make it more general than _just_ `sed`?

Comment: `sed $d file` returns an error. Instead, $d should be within quotes, like this: `sed '$d' file`

Answer (score 281, accepted):

I don't know about `sed`, but it can be done with `head`:

```
head -n -2 myfile.txt
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. The equivalent sed command is butt ugly: `sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,5ba' -e 'P;D' file` (`,5` for last 5 lines).

Comment: Note that this works with some versions of `head`, but is not standard.  Indeed, the standard for `head` states: `The application shall ensure that the number option-argument is a positive decimal integer.`

Comment: @rjdkolb thanks for your edit, but negative numbers traditionally do have a dash in front.

Comment: you have to pipe it into `tee` if you want to update the input file

Comment: That sounds unsafe; are you sure there's no race condition there? I'd imagine it would vary from shell to shell.

Comment: To add to @WilliamPursell's answer... On Mac OS default shell, this does not work.

Comment: Nor on BSD, but the question is tagged Linux.

Comment: @ams doesn't head just print to standard output? tested Ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: @codecowboy, yes, just like the sed commands in the question. You can pipe it to a new file. There's no modify-in-place option here. (Don't try to pipe it back to itself!)

Comment: minus 1, because, in addition to osx, this isn't working for me on Ubuntu14 - `head: illegal line count -- -2`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Works fine on 14.04.2 for me. Did you install `head` from something other that GNU coreutils? Try `head --version`.

Comment: For Mac and BSD folks, here's how I solved it: `some_command | tail -r | sed -e '1,3d' | tail -r`.  Note `tail -r` to reverse the buffer the `sed` command deletes the first 3 lines, and `tail -r` reverses the buffer again to put it back to the original order.

Comment: It being 2019 now, I felt inspired to use GNU head on OSX in the most overkill possible way— by using Docker: `docker run -v /Users/me/reports:/reports ubuntu head -n -7 /reports/ugly_footer.csv`

Comment: This line works with `ghead` in OSX. Install with `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 45):

If hardcoding n is an option, you can use sequential calls to sed. For instance, to delete the last three lines, delete the last one line thrice:

```
sed '$d' file | sed '$d' | sed '$d'
```

Comment: This, plus -i to edit the file in place rather than dumping it to stdout, worked for me.

Comment: Donot know why | pipe is not working, ; worked for me.

Answer (score 43):

From the [sed one-liners](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/sedoneliner.shtml):

```
# delete the last 10 lines of a file
sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,10ba' -e 'P;D'   # method 1
sed -n -e :a -e '1,10!{P;N;D;};N;ba'  # method 2
```

Seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Thor you can change how many lines are removed from the file by changing the `10` in `'$d;N;2,10ba'`

Comment: @AlexejMagura: I was commenting on an earlier version of the answer.

Comment: Sry, I'm pretty new to sed command and this looks really confusing to me. How do I specify the file to apply against with this command?

Comment: @Alex you specify the file by appending the file name after those commands e.g. `sed -e :a -e '$d;N;2,10ba' -e 'P;D' filename`

Answer (score 31):

Use `sed`, but let the shell do the math, with the goal being to use the `d` command by giving a range (to remove the last 23 lines):

```
sed -i "$(($(wc -l < file)-22)),\$d" file
```

To remove the last 3 lines, from inside out:

```
$(wc -l < file)
```

Gives the number of lines of the file: say **2196**

We want to remove the last 23 lines, so for left side or range:

```
$((2196-22))
```

Gives: **2174**
Thus the original sed after shell interpretation is:

```
sed -i '2174,$d' file
```

With `-i` doing inplace edit, file is now **2173** lines!

If you want to save it into a new file, the code is:

```
sed -i '2174,$d' file > outputfile
```

Comment: This is the right answer (sed one-liner). Let's make it a bit easier with three lines: `file=myfile.txt` `n=23` `sed -i "$(($(wc -l < $file)-n+1)),\$d" $file`

Answer (score 28):

A funny & simple `sed` and `tac` solution :

```
n=4
tac file.txt | sed "1,$n{d}" | tac
```

**NOTE**

- double quotes `"` are needed for the shell to evaluate the `$n` variable in `sed` command. In single quotes, no interpolate will be performed.
- `tac` is a `cat` reversed, see `man 1 tac`
- the `{}` in `sed` are there to separate `$n` & `d` (if not, the shell try to interpolate non existent `$nd` variable)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant `port info coreutils` || `brew info coreutils` ;

Answer (score 22):

You could use **head** for this.

Use

`$ head --lines=-N file > new_file`

where N is the number of lines you want to remove from the file.

The contents of the original file minus the last N lines are now in **new_file**

Answer (score 13):

Just for completeness I would like to add my solution.
I ended up doing this with the standard `ed`:

```
ed -s sometextfile <<< $'-2,$d\nwq'
```

This deletes the last 2 lines using in-place editing (although it *does* use a temporary file in `/tmp` !!)

Answer (score 9):

To truncate very large files truly in-place we have `truncate` command.
It doesn't know about lines, but `tail` + `wc` can convert lines to bytes:

```
file=bigone.log
lines=3
truncate -s -$(tail -$lines $file | wc -c) $file
```

There is an obvious race condition if the file is written at the same time.
In this case it may be better to use `head` - it counts bytes from the beginning of file (mind disk IO), so we will always truncate on line boundary (possibly more lines than expected if file is actively written):

```
truncate -s $(head -n -$lines $file | wc -c) $file
```

Handy one-liner if you fail login attempt putting password in place of username:

```
truncate -s $(head -n -5 /var/log/secure | wc -c) /var/log/secure
```

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;1,4ba;P;$d;D' file
```

Comment: Nice. You missed the ending apostrophe (`'`).

Comment: sorry for so late comment but i try and (adpated for my AIX/posix) it failed printing all but last line. Reading the code, i don't understand how the last four lines are removed, the explicit loop is on 4 first lines so it certainly loop after a `d`, `D` or `P` with GNU sed and not on posix version. Seems lines are not printed after the `D` and keep in working buffer for a new loop without passing to 'end' of actions line.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu the program reads in a window of 4 lines into the pattern space and then appends the next line and prints the first until it reaches the end of file where it deletes the remaining lines.

Comment: @potong yes, i test on a GNU sed and it keep the buffer between lines where posix unload it after the `D` making the opposite effect.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the above answers seem to require GNU commands/extensions:

```
    $ head -n -2 myfile.txt
    -2: Badly formed number
```

For a slightly more portible solution:

```
     perl -ne 'push(@fifo,$_);print shift(@fifo) if @fifo > 10;'
```

OR

```
     perl -ne 'push(@buf,$_);END{print @buf[0 ... $#buf-10]}'
```

OR

```
     awk '{buf[NR-1]=$0;}END{ for ( i=0; i < (NR-10); i++){ print buf[i];} }'
```

Where "10" is "n".

Answer (score 2):

With the answers here you'd have already learnt that sed is not the best tool for this application.

However I do think there is a way to do this in using sed; the idea is to append N lines to hold space untill you are able read without hitting EOF.  When EOF is hit, print the contents of hold space and quit.

```
sed -e '$!{N;N;N;N;N;N;H;}' -e x
```

The sed command above will omit last 5 lines.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in 3 steps:

a) Count the number of lines in the file you want to edit:

```
 n=`cat myfile |wc -l`
```

b) Subtract from that number the number of lines to delete:

```
 x=$((n-3))
```

c) Tell sed to delete from that line number (`$x`) to the end:

```
 sed "$x,\$d" myfile
```

Comment: Bad math. If you must delete 3 lines, then subtract 3 but ADD 1. With your math, if the file has 10 lines, 10 - 3 = 7 and you are using `sed` to delete lines 7 through 10, that is 4 lines, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total count of lines with `wc -l <file>` and use

`head -n <total lines - lines to remove> <file>`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
n = line number
tail -r file_name | sed '1,nd' | tail -r
```

Comment: Please explain how this works.  FYI - to initialize shell variables, we shouldn't have a space around `=`.

Comment: @codeforester First line was a comment I guess. He just uses `tail -r` where others have used `tac` to reverse lines order, and make the last `n` lines become the `n` first lines.

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the last 3 lines from `file`:

`for i in $(seq 1 3); do sed -i '$d' file; done;`

Comment: This is way too expensive for large files -- the entire file has to be read and rewritten n times!  And as many forks for `sed`.

Comment: while this may not be the most efficient solution, it is be far the most straightforward and easy to understand

Comment: Consider piping the sed command n-1 times into the next as described [here ⬆️](/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file#answer-24298204) to avoid readingthe file n times.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution;

```
head -$(gcalctool -s $(cat file | wc -l)-N) file
```

where *N* is the number of lines to remove.

Answer (score 0):

To delete last 4 lines:

```
$ nl -b a file | sort -k1,1nr | sed '1, 4 d' | sort -k1,1n | sed 's/^ *[0-9]*\t//'
```

Comment: a bit heavy (especially in resources) compare to a head. A least `tac file | sed '1,4d' | tac` because sort then remove prefix cost lot of ressources.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu you are right but there is no `tac` command is some systems (for example FreeBSD?)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n ':pre
1,4 {N;b pre
    }
:cycle
$!{P;N;D;b cycle
  }' YourFile
```

posix version

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, where n is the number of lines you want to delete:

```
count=`wc -l file`
lines=`expr "$count" - n`
head -n "$lines" file > temp.txt
mv temp.txt file
rm -f temp.txt
```

It's a little roundabout, but I think it's easy to follow.

1. Count up the number of lines in the main file
2. Subtract the number of lines you want to remove from the count
3. Print out the number of lines you want to keep and store in a temp file
4. Replace the main file with the temp file
5. Remove the temp file

Answer (score 0):

In docker, this worked for me:

```
head --lines=-N file_path > file_path
```

Comment: Are you sure it worked? With >> you're appending content to the end of file...

Comment: I'm sorry but this also can't work in  that way if you read and write to the same file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696842/how-can-i-use-a-file-in-a-command-and-redirect-output-to-the-same-file-without-t

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Enter the file name : '
read filename

echo 'Enter the number of lines from the end that needs to be deleted :'
read n

#Subtracting from the line number to get the nth line
m=`expr $n - 1`

# Calculate length of the file
len=`cat $filename|wc -l`

#Calculate the lines that must remain
lennew=`expr $len - $m`

sed "$lennew,$ d" $filename
```

Comment: Reading any file from the system and also selecting any of the length

Answer (score 0):

A solution similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24298204/1221137 but with editing in place and not hardcoded number of lines:

```
n=4
seq $n | xargs -i sed -i -e '$d' my_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have several lines:

```
    $ cat <<EOF > 20lines.txt
> 1
> 2
> 3
[snip]
> 18
> 19
> 20
> EOF
```

Then you can grab:

```
# leave last 15 out
$ head -n5 20lines.txt
1
2
3
4
5

# skip first 14
$ tail -n +15 20lines.txt
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: Oops!!
Duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix

Answer (score 0):

POSIX compliant solution using `ex` / `vi`, in the vein of @Michel's solution above.
@Michel's `ed` example uses "not-POSIX" Here-Strings.
Increment the `$-1` to remove `n` lines to the EOF ($), or just feed the lines you want to (d)elete. You could use `ex` to count line numbers or do any other Unix stuff.

Given the file:

```
cat > sometextfile <<EOF
one
two
three
four
five
EOF
```

Executing:

```
ex -s sometextfile <<'EOF'
$-1,$d
%p
wq!
EOF
```

Returns:

```
one
two
three
```

This uses POSIX Here-Docs so it is really easy to modify - especially using `set -o vi` with a POSIX `/bin/sh`.
While on the subject, the "ex personality" of "vim" **should** be fine, but YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

For deleting the last N lines of a file, you can use the same concept of

```
$ sed '2,4d' file
```

You can use a combo with tail command to reverse the file: if N is 5

```
$ tail -r file | sed '1,5d' file | tail -r > file
```

And this way runs also where `head -n -5 file` command doesn't run (like on a mac!).

Answer (score -2):

This will remove the last 12 lines

```
sed -n -e :a -e '1,10!{P;N;D;};N;ba'
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would help please.