# Deleting the data before character match

Tags: regex, perl, sed

How can I delete the characters before "/", including the "/", in a string using Perl or sed?

For instance, this:

```
ad9a91/FFFF0000
```

would turn into

```
FFFF0000
```

Answer (score 2):

**Sed solution**

```
sed 's|[^/]*/||' file
```

Will remove everything up to and including the first `/`

or

```
sed 's|.*/||' file
```

Will remove everything up to and including the last `/` .

I added both as the question was not entirely clear on what the format of the string would be every time.

**Awk**

```
awk -F/ '{$0=$NF}1' file
```

This replaces the entire line with whatever is after the last `/`

Comment: You should explain the difference between the first and second version (the second version replaces all until the last slash, if there are several occurences of a slash in the line)

Comment: It's based on your sample (where no more word or char than what you show). first "remove" first char until first `/` and second like you write "remove" until last one. In this case it is the same effect, not if there are surround word/char but in this case both are false (but out of context also).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Added explanations :)

Comment: thanks,also can u please tell me a sed command which deletes last 3 lines of a file

Comment: @user3383729 Post a new question or use the search function and you would find an answer. A quick search revealed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-last-n-lines-of-a-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use substitution,

```
my $str = "ad9a91/FFFF0000";
$str =~ s|^.+?/||;
```

or regex capture,

```
$str = $1 if $str =~ m|/(.+)|s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substitution for this:

```
my $string = "ad9a91/FFFF0000";
$string =~ s|\.+/||;
```

Comment: but its not a single line there are multiple lines with random data after the '/' character

Comment: @user3383729 Sorry my fault. have upated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
my $string = qq(sjdflksdjfsdj ad9a91/FFFF0000 slodjfsdf s);
$string =~ s{\b(\s).*?\b/}{$1}ig;
print $string;exit;
```

you can also try this split with any space or any tag.