# Tail how to skip last line

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am polling a csv file and want to capture the the last 5 lines of the file periodically. Is there a way to do that while skipping the last line. For example

File I'm Polling:

```
Fooo1,bar1,bar1
Fooo2,bar2,bar2
Fooo3,bar3,bar3
Fooo4,bar4,bar4
Fooo5,bar5,bar5
Fooo6,bar6,bar6
Fooo7,bar7,bar7
```

Tail command would capture lines 2-6 only.

The problem is that the file keeps growing.

Comment: Wouldn't tail -5 file.csv | head -4 work?

Comment: By *periodically* do you mean every 3 minutes, for example, you want to capture the last 5 lines? Could you be more clear what your requirements are?

Comment: Perfect! Nailed it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use sed to delete lines from command output that I know is going to have some amount of header & trailer lines.  For instance, to delete the first 3 lines and delete the last line of output:

```
system "WRKSBS" | sed -e '1,3d;$d'
```

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you use this:

```
tail -5 file.csv | head -4
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this instead:

```
head -n -1 file.csv
```

It skips last line
Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13380679/3973995).