# Delete the 3 last line of my txt with bash?

Tags: bash, sh

I search for a moment the way in my script bash, to be able to remove the 3 last lines of a file with each call of the script.

test.sh

```
head -n -3 test.txt > temp.txt ; mv temp.txt test.txt
```

result :

> head: illegal line count -- -3

test.txt - Before:

```
Name : Mike
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
Name : Mould
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
Name : May
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
```

test.txt - After (not working):

```
Name : Mike
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
Name : Mould
Surname : Tilmen
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you on a mac? It doesn't like negative line counts. May have to switch to `sed` instead.

Comment: works fine on my x86_64 linux, with bash version 4.4.12

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file for solution.