# How to use locale variable and 'delete last line' in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to delete the last three lines of a file in a shell bash script.

Since I am using local variables in combination with the Regex syntax in *sed* the answer proposed in [How to use sed to remove the last n lines of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file) does not cover this case. On the contrary, the cases covered deal with *sed* in a terminal and does not cover syntax in shell scripts, neither does it cover the use of variables in *sed* expressions.

The commands I have available is limited, since I am not on a Linux but use a MINGW64 for it.
*sed* does a create job so far, but deleting the last three lines gives me some headaches in relation of how to format the expression.

I use *wc* to be aware of how many lines the file has and subtract then with *expr* three lines.

```
n=$(wc -l < "$distribution_area")
rel=$(expr $n - 3)
```

The start point for deleting lines is defined by *rel* but accessing the local variable happens through the `$` and unfortunately the syntax of *sed* is using the `$` to define the end of file. Hence,

```
sed -i "$rel,$d" "$distribution_area"
```

won't work, and what ever variant of combinations e.g. `'"'"$rel"'",$d'` gives me *sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'* or something similar.

Can somebody show me how to combine the variable with the `$d` regex syntax of *sed*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file ?

Comment: Do you have `head` available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sed to remove the last n lines of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file)

Comment: @0stone0 I do have head and tail available

Comment: @Dexygen the answer you and several others suggesting is missing the part of how to handle the locale variable. This part is answered here by KamilCuk and 0stone0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can somebody show me how to combine the variable with the $d regex syntax of sed?

`$d` expands to a varibale `d`, you have to escape it.

```
"$rel,\$d"
```

or:

```
"$rel"',$d'
```

But I would use:

```
head -n -3 "$distribution_area" > "$distribution_area".tmp
mv "$distribution_area".tmp "$distribution_area"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "$rel,$d" "$distribution_area"
```

Here you're missing the variable name (`n`) for the second arg.

Consider the following example on a file called `test` that contains 1-10:

```
n=$(wc -l < test)
rel=$(($n - 3))

sed "$rel,$n d" test
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

To make sure the `d` will not interfere with the `$n`, you can add a space instead of escaping.

---

If you have a recent `head` available, I'd recommend something like:

```
head -n -3 test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last *N* lines using only pure Bash, without forking additional processes (such as `sed`). Such scripts look ugly, but they would work in any environment where only Bash runs and nothing else is available, no other binaries like `sed`, `awk` etc.

If the entire file fits in RAM, a straightforward solution is to split it by lines and print all but the *N* trailing ones:

```bash
delete_last_n_lines() {
  local -ir n="$1"
  local -a lines
  readarray lines
  ((${#lines[@]} > n)) || return 0
  printf '%s' "${lines[@]::${#lines[@]} - n}"
}
```

If the file does not fit in RAM, you can keep a FIFO buffer that stores *N* lines (*N* + 1 in the “implementation” below, but that’s just a technical detail), let the file (arbitrarily large) flow through the buffer and, after reaching the end of the file, ***not*** print out what remains in the buffer (the last *N* lines to remove).

```bash
delete_last_n_lines() {
  local -ir n="$1 + 1"
  local -a lines
  local -i pos i
  for ((i = 0; i < n; ++i)); do
    IFS= read -r lines[i] || return 0
  done
  printf '%s\n' "${lines[pos]}"
  while IFS= read -r lines[pos++]; do
    ((pos %= n))
    printf '%s\n' "${lines[pos]}"
  done
}
```

The following example gets 10 lines of input, `0` to `9`, but prints out only `0` to `6`, removing `7`, `8` and `9` as desired:

```bash
printf '%s' {0..9}$'\n' | delete_last_n_lines 3
```

Last but not least, this simple hack lacks `sed`’s `-i` option to edit files in-place. That could be implemented (e.g.) using a temporary file to store the output and then renaming the temporary file to the original. (A more sophisticated approach would be needed to avoid storing the temporary copy altogether. I don’t think Bash exposes an interface like `lseek()` to read files “backwards”, so this cannot be done in Bash alone.)