# Take out certain data from file

Tags: linux, unix, batch-file

How can I take out certain information from files.

For example:

> from file .txt have lot of data

```
1)a=123    
2)b=234     
3)c=345  
4)e=456
```

I want to take out information '*a*';
do I need to specific the column, row or the word?

I don't have any idea how I should do or what command should I use.
Can I use a command from batch file to do this, or should I use other program software?

Hope can help me..

Comment: You could try to search with `findstr`, for more help type `findstr /?`

Comment: `cat file.txt | grep -v "a="  > file2.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to treat the equal sign (=) as a column separator? If so, and you have awk, you can do this:

```
cat file.txt 
a=123    
b=234     
c=345  
e=456

awk -F = '{print $2}' file.txt 
123    
234     
345  
456
```

If you wish to do this programatically you can use a library to split the text on the equal sign. Most all programming languages have libraries to do this.

Comment: how about if i want to grep a couple of line, let say line 1 to line 10

Comment: @Una Nh See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
@Echo OFF
Type "Text.txt" | Find "a="
```

The mid way:

```
@Echo OFF
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%a in ('Type "Text.txt" ^| Find "a="') Do (Echo %%a, %%b)
```

The usefull way:

```
@Echo OFF

:: TEXT MANIPULATOR ROUTINE v0.1
:: by Elektro H@cker

REM USE:
::TEXTMAN [ACTION] [IN LINE (Optional)] [FILE] [TEXT (Optional)]


REM ACTIONS:
REM 
REM  AL  = ADD_LEFT           * Add text to the beginning of a line
REM  AR  = ADD_RIGHT          * Add text to the end of a line
REM  E   = ERASE              * Delete a line
REM  I   = INSERT             * Add a empty line (Or a line with text)
REM  RL  = REPLACE_LINE       * Replace a line
REM  RS  = REPLACE_STRING     * Replace words of a line
REM  RSA = REPLACE_STRING_ALL * Replace words of all line
REM  C+  = CHARACTER_PLUS     * Delete the first "X" characters in all lines
REM  C-  = CHARACTER_LESS     * Delete the last  "X" characters in all lines
REM  L+  = LINE_PLUS          * Cut the first "X" lines
REM  L-  = LINE_LESS          * Cut the last  "X" lines


REM EXAMPLES:

:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
::
:: Deletes the line 3
:: Call :TEXTMAN E 3 "Test.txt"
::
:: Add a phrase to the beginning of line 3
:: Call :TEXTMAN AL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"
::
:: Add a phrase to the end of line 3
:: Call :TEXTMAN AR 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"
::
:: Add a empty line at line 3
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt"
:: 
:: Add a line with a word at line 3
:: Call :TEXTMAN I 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"
::
:: Replaces the line 3 with "Elektro H@cker"
:: Call :TEXTMAN RL 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro H@cker"
::
:: Replaces the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in line 3
:: Call :TEXTMAN RS 3 "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"
::
:: Replaces the words "Elektro" to "H@cker" in all lines
:: Call :TEXTMAN RSA "Test.txt" "Elektro" "H@cker"
::
:: Deletes the first 3 characters in all lines
:: Call :TEXTMAN C+ 3 "Test.txt"
::
:: Deletes the last 3 characters in all lines
:: Call :TEXTMAN C- 3 "Test.txt"
::
:: Deletes the first 3 lines
:: Call :TEXTMAN L+ 3 "Test.txt"
::
:: Deletes the last 3 lines
:: Call :TEXTMAN L- 3 "Test.txt"
::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::

:TEXTMAN
(SET /A "A=0", "LINE=0", "TOTAL_LINES=0")  &  (CALL :%~1 %* || (ECHO Parametro incorrecto & Exit /B 1)) & (GOTO:EOF)
:AL
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (Echo %%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW") ELSE (Echo %~4%%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:AR
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (Echo %%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW") ELSE (Echo %%@%~4 >> "%~nx3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:E
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (Echo %%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:I
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF     "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (IF NOT "%~4" EQU "" (Echo %~4 >> "%~nx3.NEW") ELSE (Echo. >> "%~nx3.NEW"))" & Echo %%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RL
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (Echo %%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW") ELSE (Echo %~4 >> "%~nx3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RS
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" && (CMD /C "IF NOT "%%LINE%%" EQU "%~2" (Echo %%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW") ELSE (CALL SET "STRING=%%@" && CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~4=%~5%% >> "%~nx3.NEW")"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:RSA
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~2") DO (CALL SET "STRING=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%STRING:%~3=%~4%% >> "%~2.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~2") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C+
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~%~2%% >>    "%~nx3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:C-
(For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set   "LINE=%%@" && (CALL ECHO %%LINE:~0,-%~2%% >> "%~nx3.NEW"))) && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L+
(Call SET /A "A=%~2-1") && (Call TYPE "%~3" | @MORE +%%A%% > "%~nx3.NEW") && (CALL :RENAMER "%~3") & (GOTO:EOF)
:L-
(FOR /F %%X IN ('TYPE "%~3"') DO (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES+=1")) & (CALL SET /A "TOTAL_LINES-=%~2-1") & (For /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%@ in ("%~3") DO (Call Set /A "LINE+=1" & Call echo " %%LINE%%!!| FINDSTR " %%TOTAL_LINES%% " && CALL :RENAMER "%~3" && GOTO:EOF || (Echo %%@ >> "%~nx3.NEW")))
:RENAMER
(REN "%~1" "%~nx1.BAK") & (MOVE /Y "%~nx1.BAK" "%TEMP%\" >NUL) & (REN "%~nx1.NEW" "%~nx1") & (GOTO:EOF)
```