# Grep only a part of a text file

Tags: linux, grep, text-processing

How can I apply the following command to only a part of a text file? For example from the beginning to the line 5000.

```
grep "^  A : 11  B : 10" filename | wc -l
```

I cannot use head and then apply the above command since the text file is huge.

Comment: Why won't `head -5000 filename` in front of `grep` work? Even if the file is huge, it should work.

Comment: 5000 was just an example. I am working on the text files in GB scale, so, I guess that for the cases much much bigger than 5000 I may run out of memory/Disk.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the sed command, which I believe does better for large files, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix) question and pipe to grep.

```
sed -n 1,5000p file | grep ...
```

Comment: Actually, since `sed` is already a superset of basic `grep`, make that `sed -n -e 5000q -e '/^  A : 11  B : 10/p' filename | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

You can try combination of -n (prefixing each line of output with line number) and -m (limiting number of matching lines). Something like this:

```
grep -n -m 5000 pattern file.txt | grep -B 5000 "^5000:" | wc -l
```

First grep search for pattern, add line numbers and limit output to first 5000 matching lines (worst case scenario: all lines from range match pattern). Second grep match line number 5000, and print all lines before this line.

I don't know if it is more efficient solution