# how to cut lines from file and move to new file in linux

Tags: linux

I am looking for something some simple command to cut a few lines from file1 and paste them in file2.

I can see a few blogs to copy but don't see anything how to cut them. Any help would be great.

Eg: File1: Move SA & DBA lines to new file(file2)

DevOps

QA

Engineering

SA

DBA

Comment: There's a cut command https://shapeshed.com/unix-cut/, theres awk... Lots of ways to do it.

Comment: What programming language do you wish to use?

Comment: I just want to remove 3 lines from the file. Bash script will help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -n begin_line,end_line[p] filename > newfile && sed -i 'begin_line,end_line d' filename
```

From [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands).

Related question and study:

[How can I extract a predetermined range of lines from a text file on Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix)

Comment: When I tried this, it is copying the lines but it is not deleting from the file1. I want to cut (remove/delete) the lines from file1 and past it in file2.