# how to copy lines 10 to 15 of a file into another file, in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

I want to copy lines 10 to 15 of a file into another file in Unix.

I am having files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

I want to copy lines 10 to 15 from `file1.txt` to `file2.txt`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract a predetermined range of lines from a text file on Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Open a terminal with a shell then

```
sed -n '10,15p' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Simple & easy.

If you want to append to the end instead of wiping `file2.txt`, use `>>` for redirection.

```
sed -n '10,15p' file1.txt >> file2.txt
                          ^^
```

AWK is also a powerful command line text manipulator:

```
awk 'NR>=10 && NR<=15' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: what if the `file2.txt ` has some contents and we want to insert at the start of `file2.txt`
@iBug

Comment: @JigarGandhi "Insert at start" is really another topic. Your best bet is to save the output to `file3.txt` and then append the original file (`cat file2.txt >> file3.txt`).

Comment: If I want to pass the line number 10 & 15 of sed using two variables say start_line & end_line then what to do?

Comment: @SoumyadipDas Just use shell variable processing: `sed -n "${start_line},${end_line}p"`. Make sure you avoid single quotes where no variable substitution happens.

Comment: Nice, it's the easiest one. I did something with the help of https://askubuntu.com/a/76842 and working, but I will now use your's solution in my shell.

Answer (score 16):

In complement to the previous answer, you can use one of the following 3 solutions.

**sed**

Print only the lines in the range and redirect it to the output file

```
sed -n '10,15p' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

**head/tail combination**

Use head and tail to cut the file and to get only the range you need before redirecting the output to a file

```
head -n 15 file1.txt | tail -n 6 > file2.txt
```

**awk**

Print only the lines in the range and redirect it to the output file

```
awk 'NR>=10 && NR<=15' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: The head/tail is only an accomplishment of the job, not a good answer in fact. The AWK solution is a really good one.