# How can I print lines using sed Command?

Tags: sed

Can someone tell me a 'one line' sed command that prints out the lines 100-104 and 205-210 of of any file that has 500 lines in total ?

I tried this one :

```
sed -n '100,104'p unique_undetermined
```

Comment: you can issue multiple commands separated by `;`

Comment: The requirement to only process files with 500 lines or more complicates your problem (as does your "need" to have a one-liner (these are highly overrated!)) . . You could surround your  improved `sed` cmd per Sundeep's comment with `if (( $(wc -l < fileName) > 500 )) ; then `sed ... ; else echo file not big enough to process ; fi` . Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract a predetermined range of lines from a text file on Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix)

Answer (score -1):

@Sundeep is suggesting the following:

```
sed -n '100,104p;205,210p' unique_undetermined
```

Comment: Yes you can use `-e '100,104p;205,210p'` or `-e '100,104p' -e '205,210p'`.