# Extract lines from text file, using starting line number and amount of lines to extract, in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I have seen [How can I extract a predetermined range of lines from a text file on Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83329/how-can-i-extract-a-predetermined-range-of-lines-from-a-text-file-on-unix) but I have a slightly different use case: I want to specify a starting line number, and a count/amount/number of lines to extract, from a text file.

So, I tried to generate a text file, and then compose an awk command to extract a count of 10 lines starting from line number 100 - but it does not work:

```
$ seq 1 500 > test_file.txt
$ awk 'BEGIN{s=100;e=$s+10;} NR>=$s&&NR<=$e' test_file.txt
$
```

So, what would be an easy approach to extract lines from a text file using a starting line number, and count of lines, in bash? (I'm ok with `awk`, `sed`, or any such tool, for instance in `coreutils`)

Comment: remove all the `$` inside the `awk` code

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${start}+$int" %p Q | ed -s file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

This gives you text that is *inclusive* of both end points
(eleven output lines, here).

```
$ START=100
$
$ sed -n "${START},$((START + 10))p"  < test_file.txt
```

The `-n` says "no print by default".

And then the `p` says "print this line",
for lines within the example range of 100,110

Comment: or with GNU sed: `sed -n "${START},+10p" test_file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use `awk`, use something like

```
seq 1 500 | awk 'NR>=100 && NR<=110'
```

Advantage of `awk` is the flexibility for changing the requirements.
When you want to use a variable `start` and skip the endpoints, it will be

```
start=100
seq 1 500 | awk -v start="${start}" 'NR > start && NR < start + 10'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n "$Start,$End p" file
```

is likely a better way to get those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative with `tail` and `head`:

```
tail -n +$START test_file.txt | head -n $NUMBER
```

If `test_file.txt` is very large and `$START` and `$NUMBER` are small, the following variant should be the fastest:

```
head -n $((START+NUMBER)) test_file.txt | tail -n +$START
```

Anyway, I prefer the `sed` solution noticed above for short input files:

```
sed -n "$START,$((START+NUMBER)) p" test_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ seq 1 500 > test_file.txt
$ awk 'BEGIN{s=100;e=$s+10;} NR>=$s&&NR<=$e' test_file.txt
$
```

`$s` in GNU `AWK` means value of `s`-th field, `$e` in GNU `AWK` means value of `e`-th field. There are not fields yet in `BEGIN` clause so `$s` for any `s` is not set, as you use in arithemtic context it will be assumed to be `0` and therefore `e` will be set to value `10`. Output of `seq` is single number per line, so there is not 10th field, so GNU `AWK` assumes it to be zero when asked to compare it with number, as `NR` is always strictly bigger than `0` your condition never holds so output is empty.

Use [Range](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) if you are able to prepare condition which holds solely for starting line and condition which holds solely for ending line, in this case

```
awk 'BEGIN{s=100}NR==s,NR==s+10' test_file.txt
```

gives output

```
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
```

Keep in mind that this will process whole file, if you have huge file and area of interest is relatively near begin, then you might decrease time consumption by ending processing at end of area of interest following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{s=100}NR>=s{print}NR==s+10{exit}' test_file.txt
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

This command extracts 30 lines starting from line 100

```
sed -n '100,$p' test_file.txt | head -30
```